# DOCUSIGN - Getting other tabs or fields to populate within the docusign signing process

Tags: docusignapi

Here is some of my PHP code I am using which works to grab the signature of the user no problem.However when I attempt to add another field for "datestart" I get nothing to show up on the PDF document within Docusign Demo. So basically I'm unable to get any other fields to populate within my Docusign signature besides the signature name and email when it comes to the signing part. Am I doing something wrong within my code? I used the code examples that docusign provided but with no luck.

More Insight: I am just trying to populate basic text fields that docusign provides. Nothing else at the moment.

```
 # The signer object
    $signer = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Signer([ 
        'email' => $signerEmail, 'name' => $signerName, 'recipient_id' => "1", 'routing_order' => "1",
        'client_user_id' => $clientUserId # Setting the client_user_id marks the signer as embedded
    ]);

    $signHere = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\SignHere([ # DocuSign SignHere field/tab
        'document_id' => '1', 
        'page_number' => '2', 
        'recipient_id' => '1', 
        'tab_label' => 'Signaturebottom', 
        'x_position' => '71', 
        'y_position' => '629'
    ]);


//Here is the tab+text I am having troubles getting to show up below within my docusign pdf
//Just need extra fields to populate like dates and other peoples names and mailing address etc.
$tripdates = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Text([
            'anchor_string' => '/dateone/', 'anchor_units' => 'pixels',
            'anchor_y_offset' => '409', 'anchor_x_offset' => '105',
            'font' => "helvetica", 'font_size' => "size11",
            'bold' => 'true', 'value' => "test",
            'locked' => 'true', # mark the field as readonly
            'tab_id' => 'datestart', 'tab_label' => 'datestart'
        ]);


    # Add the tabs to the signer object
    # The Tabs object wants arrays of the different field/tab types
    $signer->setTabs(new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Tabs(
    ['sign_here_tabs' => [$signHere],
    'text_tabs' => [$tripdates]
    ]));
    

    # Next, create the top level envelope definition and populate it.
    $envelopeDefinition = new DocuSign\eSign\Model\EnvelopeDefinition([
        'email_subject' => "Please sign this document",
        'documents' => [$document], # The order in the docs array determines the order in the envelope
        'recipients' => new DocuSign\eSign\Model\Recipients(['signers' => [$signer]]), # The Recipients object wants arrays for each recipient type
        'status' => "sent" # requests that the envelope be created and sent.
    ]);
```

Comment: by populate you mean the fields don't show, or they show but without the value you expect?

Comment: Yeah I can't seem to get anything else to fill out within the PDF document besides the Signature. The text fields I just for some reason can't get anything to fill with any value I throw at it. Here are my fields currently and only the signatures work: https://i.imgur.com/1pllki7.png

Comment: did you see my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because you're missing these:

```
'document_id' => '1', 
'page_number' => '2', 
'recipient_id' => '1',
```

Which you had for the signerTab but not for the textTab?